# calculate specific values of counter inside foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate specific values of a counter in my foreach loop.

I have this if statement in my code

```
if ( $i == 21 || $i == 41 || $i == 61 || $i == 81 || $i == 101 )
```

which are equal to

```
($i * 20) + 1
```

Instead of writing all these values (21,41,61,81...) I want to create a formula for my code but I couldn't figure out what the result should be equal to inside my if statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use modulus:

`if ($i % 20 == 1) { ...`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: does it output these values ?  (21,41,61,81...)

Comment: It will calculate if `$i` is 21, 41, 61 or 81. Note that it will also match 1, so you  might want `if ($i % 20 == 1 && $i > 1) {` if you do not want to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the remainder after dividing by 20 using the % operator (modulus).

```
if ($i%20 == 1)
{
    // do stuff
}
```